# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when using lambda function in pandas.apply

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Thanks for helping me today with my question.

I have a df like this below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzDSd.png)

As you can see there is dict type in the column **value**

There are three keys for these dict in the column **value**

offer id, offer_id, and transaction

I try to create a new column that gets the value from the offer id and offer_id

I tried using lambda in this but it fails

```
test2['test'] = transcript.value.apply(lambda x: list(x.values())[0] if (list(x.keys())[0] in ['offer id', 'offer_id']) )
```

Just wondering why it keeps saying "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Thanks again for helping!

-------------------solution--------------------

Thanks for all you guys help

```
test1['test'] = test1.value.apply(lambda x: list(x.values())[0] if (list(x.keys())[0] in ['offer id', 'offer_id']) else np.NaN)
```

adding the else statement it works......

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `if` in an expression, you **must** write an `else` clause too. For example:

```py
>>> x = 5
>>> 1 if x > 0 else 0
1
>>> 1 if x > 0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 if x > 0
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The reason is that an expression should result in a value, so `if` in an expression doesn't make sense unless you say what the result should be in both cases. If you don't say what the result should be when the condition is false, then the expression wouldn't result in a value in that case.

So, your code has a syntax error because you didn't write `else` to say what the result should be when `list(x.keys())[0]` is not in `['offer id', 'offer_id']`.

Answer (score 0):

`test2['test'] = transcript.value.apply(lambda x: list(x.values())[0] if (list(x.keys())[0] in ['offer id', 'offer_id']) else 'what do you want x to be if the if statement is not fulfilled?')`

Comment: It's not a statement; it's an expression. Statements don't need to produce values, but expressions do!